# Transitions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to add a `search bar` that extends itself on `subscribe button`, and I can't delay the button's display value with `JQuery click event`. 
If I use another hover function in `js`, it ignores `click event`, and `transitions`doesn't work as well. 
 It is my first post,so, I'm sorry if I made any mistake.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top container" id="navbar">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="file:///C:/Users/Eren/Desktop/HTML-CSS/Project-BlackKnight/Project-BlackKnight.html?">Black Knight</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                                <div class="container-2">
                                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                                    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
                                </div>
                                <li class="subs"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subscribe" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Subscribe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar { border: none; box-shadow: none; }

.navbar.affix {    
position: fixed;    
top: 0;    
z-index:10;    
}

.container-2 {
width: 200px;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
}

.container-2 input#search {    
width: 50px;    
height: 50px;    
background: #2b303b;    
border: none;    
font-size: 10pt;    
float: left;    
color: #262626;    
padding-left: 45px;    
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;    
-moz-border-radius: 5px;    
border-radius: 5px;    
color: #fff;    
-webkit-transition: width .70s ease;    
-moz-transition: width .70s ease;    
-ms-transition: width .70s ease;    
-o-transition: width .70s ease;    
transition: width .70s ease;    
}

.container-2 input#search::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #65737e; }    
.container-2 input#search:-moz-placeholder { color: #65737e; }    
.container-2 input#search::-moz-placeholder { color: #65737e; }    
.container-2 input#search:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #65737e; }    

.container-2 .icon {    
position: absolute;    
top: 50%;    
margin-left: 17px;    
margin-top: 17px;    
z-index: 1;    
color: #4f5b66;    
}

.container-2 input#search:focus, .container-2 input#search:active { outline:none; width: 200px; }    
.container-2:hover+.subs{ display: none; }    
\#search { position: absolute; }    
.subs { margin-left: 45px; transition: 5s all 5s ease; }    //this is the problem
.container-2:hover input#search { width: 200px; }    
.container-2:hover .icon { color: #93a2ad; }
```

js:

```
$('.navbar').affix ( {
offset: {
    top: function () {
  return (this.bottom = $('.top-images').height());
}
}
});

$('#search').click(
function() {
    $('.subs').hide();
}
);

$(document).click(
function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is('#search')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.subs').show();
        }, 500);
    }
    if (!$(e.target).is('#search')) {
        $('.modal').modal(toggle)
    }
    if ($(e.target).is('.sub-button')) {
        $('.modal').modal(toggle)
    }
}
);
```

If you have any more effective ideas, I'm open for suggestions.
Thank you in advance! 
Here is a fiddle with my code: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xj90w699/2/)

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: Okay here is the problem: when my search bar extends it makes subscribe button 'display = none;' and when it comes back again it comes before search bar collapsed succesfully and it looks nested for a sec.

Comment: So, when the subscribe button displays, you want to display in the same line with transition. Am I right?

Comment: yes i need a delay time for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delay` when you `show/hide` an element. For example, on you case, change this `JQuery` code:

```
    if (!$(e.target).is('#search')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.subs').show();
    }, 500);
   }
```

to:

```
   if (!$(e.target).is('#search')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.subs').delay(1000).fadeIn();
    }, 100);
   }
```

And remove `margin` in your `li`:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
 margin: 0;
}
```

Finally, here is a fiddle: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vs36ur9L/8/)
You can make with `hover event` too. 
 I made another fiddle with `hover`:
[hover function](https://jsfiddle.net/vs36ur9L/12/) 
Hope this is what you've been looking for!

Comment: The one with `hover` is exactly what I need but it would be more useful if I can click on `search bar` :) I don't know what the problem is and how to solve it but it is about js.

Comment: You mean to encrase the width on input on hover,and remove that width when clicking somewhere else? Am I right?

Comment: not really; I need to increase the width when hover and keep it if I click then I remove it when clicking somewhere else and if I don't click it will decrease on `mouseleave`.

Comment: @ErenKoç, this is exactly what this fiddle do!

Comment: Thank you. The first one wasn't doing the click function but now it is perfect, thank you.
Edit: it doesn't works properly again it dismisses `subscribe` button on hover and it doesn't come back unless you click on search :(

Comment: `$('#search').mouseleave(
function() {

    $('.container-2 input').removeClass('focus');
  $('.subs').delay(1000).fadeIn();
    $('input').blur();
}
);`

Comment: @ErenKoç, glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to make exactly but check thi [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yccbkkp6/2/)
I have fixed that `data-target='#subscribe'` to `data-target='#search'`
Check it and let me know what else do you want to get

Comment: no that is not what i need i use subs button for a modal outside of navbar.